# Are there any real-world application in a bone fracture detection program?

Tags: medical-device, diagnosis, medical-imaging, bone-fractures, technology

Sorry if I'm asking in the wrong community, but here's where I think I can reach more people in the medical field.

I am in engineering, for a project in my uni, I thought of doing a research on using computer vision and machine learning to detect bone fractures in X-Ray images (very general description, the title can still be changed).

Before I start investing time into this research, I would like to know if there are any real-world value in a bone fracture detection program. What are your advice/opinions on this project?